# awk '{print $9}' the last ls -l column including any spaces in the file name

Tags: bash, awk

How would I get awk to output the whole file name in `ls -l` if some of the files have spaces in them. Usually, I can run this command:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $9}'
```

That doesn't work if the files have spaces in them. Is it possible to print $9, $10, $11 etc as well somehow?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A better solution: Don't attempt to parse ls output in the first place.

The official wiki of the irc.freenode.org #bash channel has an explanation of why this is a Bad Idea, and what alternate approaches you can take instead: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Use of find, [stat](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087) and similar tools will provide the functionality you're looking for without the pitfalls (not all of which are obvious -- some occur only when moving to platforms with different ls implementations).

For your specific example, I'm guessing that you're trying to find only files (and not directories) in your current directory; your current implementation using `ls -l` is buggy, as it excludes files which have +t or setuid permissions. The Right Way to implement this would be the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

Comment: Consider the use of \0 in place of \n if you're feeding the output into another command like `grep -z` or `xargs -0`. This makes `-printf` work like `-print0`.

Comment: How i can use this, but filter by extension, for example .txt ?

Comment: @inukaze, put `-name '*.txt'` before the `-printf`

Answer (score 5):

Just for completion. It can also be done with sed:

```
# just an exercise in regex matching ...
ls -l | sed -E  -e '1d; s/^([^ ]+ +){8}//'
```

Comment: @mikk Can you explain your command? I think `-e /^[^-]/d` is stripping out symlinks and `-e 's/^([^ ]+ +){8}//'` is printing the 9th column that doesn't start with a space, but what does `-e 1d` do?

Comment: @Dannid, looks to me like it's deleting the first line. Quoting from the POSIX spec to explain why: If any of the `-l`, `-g`, `-n`, `-o`, or `-s` options is specified, each list of files within the directory shall be preceded by a status line indicating the number of file system blocks occupied by files in the directory in 512-byte units, rounded up to the next integral number of units, if necessary. In the POSIX locale, the format shall be:

`"total %u\n", <number of units in the directory>`

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a better approach that involves combining fields somehow, but:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14... | 
  awk '{for (i = 9 ; i <= NF ; i++) printf "%s ", $i}'
9 10 11 12 13 14...
```

Using `printf "%s " $i` will print the i-th field with a space after it, instead of a newline.  The for loop just says to go from field 9 to the last field.

Comment: this will fail when there is a double space

Answer (score 2):

If you still insist on the ls -l instead of find or other tools, here is my solution. It is not pretty and destructive:

1. Destroy $1 .. $8 by setting them to "" via a for loop
2. That leaves a bunch of spaces preceding $9, remove them using the sub() command
3. Print out the remaining

```
ls -l | awk '{for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) $i = ""; sub(/^ */, ""); print}'
```

Comment: More care is required if you've configured `ls` to show you symbolic links (with a `-> /path/to/file` at the end); strip it with `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 | 
  awk 'BEGIN {OFS=ORS=""} ; {for (i=9;i<NF;i++) print $i " "; print $NF "\n"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to encode & decode the space with a word or character by using sed:

```
ls -l | sed s/\ /{space}/ | awk '{print $9}' | sed s/{space}/\ /
```

This will replace all spaces in a line with `{space}` before passing it to awk. After the line has passed to awk, we replace `{space}` back with space.

`find` as stated by others is a much better solution. But if you really have to use awk, you can try this.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -l | awk -v x=9 '{print $x}'
```

I use this for getting filenames of a directory without incident. I noted the find solution which is fine and dandy if you are unsure of the file types, if you know what you are looking at the ls -l works just fine, it also alphabetically orders by default.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. Setting a variable x to 9 and then printing the x’th field is the same as just writing `{print $9}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in filenames, then don’t parse `ls -l` output and use `ls -1` (number *one*, not lowercase *L*!). It simply outputs one filename per line.

```
$ touch foo 'bar with spaces' baz
$ ls -1
bar with spaces
baz
foo
```