# How can I get rid of bash: $1: ambiguous redirect on xargs command

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to execute several files with sql setences on a given database:

```
ls -lah | grep "sql$"  | awk '{print $9}' | xargs mysql -uanuser -papassword a_database < $1
```

But I getting the error:

```
bash: $1: ambiguous redirect
```

If I change the command on xargs to a simple `echo $1` it works

I already tried double quotes like this: `xargs mysql -uanuser -papassword a_database < "$1"` and this `"xargs mysql -uanuser -papassword a_database < $1"` with no luck the terminal bring another error:

```
xargs: mysql -uanuser -papassword a_database < {}: No such file or directory
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: ls -lah | grep "sql$"  | awk '{print $9}' | xargs | mysql -uanuser -papassword a_database < $1

Comment: Hi @IndraUprade it tried but give me this error:

`bash: $1: ambiguous redirect
xargs: echo: terminated by signal 13`

Comment: One other problem is that `xargs` already is getting its standard input from the pipe, and the `<` applies `xargs`, not `mysql`. As far as I know, it isn't possible to run a command with `xargs` and read from standard input.

Comment: Thanks @chepner I'll try another approach
Regards.

Comment: If you are still keen on using `xargs` you can `find . -name \*.sql -print0 | xargs -n1 -I{} -0 bash -c "mysql -uanuser -papassword a_database < '{}'"`.

Comment: Hey @alvits thanks, it worked as you wrote it.

But I tried to modify my original command, but, it still fails

Comment: Hey @alvits, thank to you, I figure it out, thank you very much, sometimes I need regexp in directories with multiple files, here is my original command working:

 `ls -lha | grep "sql$" | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -t -n1 -I{} bash -c "mysql -uanuser -papassword a_database < '{}'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `ls -l | grep | awk`, hust use a simple for loop on `*.sql` files:

```
for f in *.sql; do
   mysql -uanuser -papassword a_database < "$f"
done
```

Comment: Yes if it is written in one line then `;` is needed before `done`

Comment: This works for me thanks it only needs a little bit change a semicolon before done `for f in *.sql; do mysql -uanuser -papassword a_database < "$f"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xargs method working:

```
ls -lha | grep "sql$" | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -t -n1 -I{} bash -c "mysql -uanuser -papassword a_database < '{}'"
```

Comment: [Don't parse output of `ls`, it is error prone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1447925/548225)

Comment: This `ls -lha | grep "sql$" | awk '{print $9}'` should be replaced with `find . -type f -name "*.sql" -print0`. And `-0` should be passed as an option to `xargs` to parse the output of `find` correctly. This will work even when filenames contain spaces, newlines, tabs ....

Comment: Thanks @alvits in the process I found too the `-t` parameter of `xargs` that print commands before executing them combined with `-p` one can check if the commands are ok before execute them, I learned a lot!